# cocos2d schedule function leads to EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I scheduled a function called `Enemyshoot()` every 2 sec. In the function, I access a random object in an "`enemies`" vector which stores all the enemy objects. Meanwhile, the enemy is destroyed during the two second. I find that when i schedule the `enemyshoot()` function and it might access the already destroyed enemy object, which would report the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. What should I do?

```
 std::vector<Enemy*> enemies;


    this->schedule(schedule_selector(GameScene::enemyShoot), ENEMY_SHOOT_FREQUENCY);


    void GameScene::enemyShoot(float dt) {
    auto random = int(CCRANDOM_0_1()*(enemies.size()-1));
    Enemy *tempEnemy = enemies.at(random);
    new EnemyMissle(this,tempEnemy->enemy->getPosition().x,tempEnemy->enemy->getPosition().y);
    }

//this is where I delete the enemy object

    if((ENEMY_COLLISION_BITMASK==a>getCollisionBitmask()&&PLAYER_MISSLE_COLLISION_BITMASK==b->getCollisionBitmask())||(ENEMY_COLLISION_BITMASK==b->getCollisionBitmask()&&PLAYER_MISSLE_COLLISION_BITMASK==a->getCollisionBitmask())){

        //add the score and refresh the score label
        score+=10;
        __String *tempScore = __String::createWithFormat("score: %i",score);

        //traversing all the enemy objects to find the collided enemy
        scoreLabel->setString(tempScore->getCString());
           for(int i=0;i<enemies.size();i++){
            if((enemies.at(i)->enemy->getPhysicsBody()==b))
               enemies.erase(enemies.begin()+i);
            }
        remainingEnemies--;
        this->removeChild(b->getOwner());
        this->removeChild(a->getOwner());

         //if it is the last enemy spaceship, go to the game over scene.
        if (enemies.size()==0)GameScene::GoToGameOverScene(score);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an array of enemies to delete instead of deleting them in your loop and parse this array after to really delete them